# UTF8 fix in Ruby On Rails - how to iverride concat method?

Tags: methods, overriding, activesupport

Hope someone will help me :)

So i was having problems with utf8 encoding, when using utf8 chars in my views, for example, from db..

I got this error:

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

And btw, it wasnt a problem wih coding from db..
Anyway, I found the solution for my problem, and it was, to change method in

```
Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activesupport-3.2.6\lib\active_support\core_ext\string\output_safety.rb
```

The method i changed was "concat". So i changed this method:

```
def concat(value)
  if !html_safe? || value.html_safe?
    super(value)
  else
    super(ERB::Util.h(value))
  end
end
alias << concat
```

to this:

```
def concat(value)
  value = (value).force_encoding('UTF-8')
  if !html_safe? || value.html_safe?
    super(value)
  else
    super(ERB::Util.h(value))
  end
end
alias << concat
```

But ofcourse its a bad idea, since, the app wont work on other servers..

So i want to override this method from my initializers, so i created:

```
config/initializers/utf8_fix.rb
```

with this code:

```
module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
  class SafeBuffer < String
    def self.concat(value)
      value = (value).force_encoding('UTF-8')
      puts "--------------------------------"
      puts "Loaded concat in utf8fix.rb"
      puts "--------------------------------"
      if !html_safe? || value.html_safe?
        super(value)
      else
        super(ERB::Util.h(value))
      end
    end
    alias << concat
  end
end
```

But it seems that it dosnt override the default method. So can someone tell me, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "concat" is not class method i dosnt need self before it, so that was my problem..

Solved changing:

```
def self.concat(value)
```

to:

```
def concat(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

some fix for the above answer:

```
module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
    class SafeBuffer < String
        def concat(value)
          if value.is_a?String
            value = value.dup if value.frozen?
            value = (value).force_encoding('UTF-8')
            puts "--------------------------------"
            puts "Loaded concat in utf8fix.rb"
            puts "--------------------------------"
          end
          if !html_safe? || value.html_safe?
            super(value)
          else
            super(ERB::Util.h(value))
          end
      end
      alias << concat
    end
  end
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please elaborate on your answer. Tell what are you proposing and explain why it's proper solution.

Comment: The overriding method may not get expected string type, so I put .is_a to detect.  Otherwise, nothing changed.  The other issue is the string may freeze, so I create a clone to handle UTF8 conversion.